# How to deploy NextJS 14 to cpanel

Tags: next.js, deployment, cpanel, next.js14

**I need help**, how do I deploy NextJS 14.1 to cpanel? has anyone ever done it and succeeded?

I have tried using *server.js* and changed the *run start* to *"NODE_ENV=production node server.js"*. But *error 500* and can't, see many tutorials indeed the practice is used for next version 13